# Type 'Ref<CandyMachineAccount | undefined>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs3, metaplex, candy-machine

I got this code:

```
const [ candyMachine, setCandyMachine ] = ref<CandyMachineAccount>()
//     ^^^^^^^^^ Error Here ^^^^^^^^^
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Type 'Ref<CandyMachineAccount | undefined>' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.
```

this is `CandyMachineAccount`

```
export interface CandyMachineAccount {
  id: anchor.web3.PublicKey;
  program: anchor.Program;
  state: CandyMachineState;
}
```

My Code is based off of this React repo: [Fair-launch](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex/tree/master/js/packages/fair-launch)

There it is written like this:

```
const [candyMachine, setCandyMachine] = useState<CandyMachineAccount>();
```

I assume the issue is me writing invalid Vue Syntax?
(I use Vue3/Composition API)

Comment: `useState` returns an array, which is why you can use [array destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) on it. `ref` apparently does not return an array.

Comment: You should destructure a ref in a place where you use it, not instantly., It's done with `unref` or `someRef.value`. This was the same in React refs, so it's unclear why it's a problem.

Comment: @NicholasTower So do I need to write: `const candyMachine=ref<CandyMachineAccount()` ?

Comment: I don't have experience with vue, so i'm not sure how `ref` is intended to be used. But if you want to assign the return value to a variable, then yes, you would write `const candyMachine = ref<CandyMachineAccount>()` The error is just pointing out that the return value is not an array (or other iterable), so you can't treat it as one.